# Can't find module for iperf3 on python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5, debian-7.6.0, iperf3

I'm trying to use `iperf3` on `python3`, so first I installed the `iperf3` package on my `Debian Linux VM`, after that I could verify that all worked fine on `Python 2.7`.

However, when tried to import the `iperf3` module using `Python 3.5` (in the same VM) I got the following message:

```
File"<stdin>", line 1, in<module>
ImportError: No module named 'iperf3'
```

I tried to add the location of the iperf directory  using the `sys.path.append()` command, but still no luck.

Any idea on what I'm missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the iperf3 python wrapper. After installing it via pip3 all worked fine.